# OpenCV Python - Cannot import contrib modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, windows-7, opencv3.1

I managed to successfully build and install `OpenCV 3.1.0` on my laptop. However, on my desktop, any attempt to import a `opencv_contrib` module into Python fails with the message `"cannot import name ..."`. The `DLLs` have been generated and the `Dependency Walker` has no problem finding them (there was an issue with `DLL` location when I was doing the installation on my laptop).

The setup on the two machines appears to be the same. But I'm not too sure about that as I don't really know where the problem might be. Both machines use `Windows 7` and `Python 2.7`. The only difference during the build process was that on the desktop I was building `OpenCV` with `CUDA` enabled.

Please help.

Comment: All contrib module are not able to import? Can you post the trackback of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.6/3.5 you could use *.whl (Python on Wheels) module [from here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv):

```
pip install opencv_python-3.2.0+contrib-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

For Python 2.7 there is no opencv+contrib in one module, but you could separately install opencv module without contrib [from here at the end of the page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python) and then add `opencv-contrib-python` module:

```
pip install opencv_python-3.2.0.7-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Do not mix opencv+contrib `opencv-python (3.2.0+contrib)` and `opencv-contrib-python (3.2.0.7)` modules, otherwise your "`import cv2`" stop to work till you delete `opencv-contrib-python` module.